# How does Python call C?

Tags: python, c, dynamic-linking

How exactly can Python call a C library? Tensorflow, for example, I believe is written mostly in C, but can be used from Python. I'm thinking of implementing something like this in my own (interpreted) programming language (written in Go, but I assume it would be a similar process).

What happens when a Python program calls a C function? I'm thinking either RPC or DLLs, but both of them seem unlikely.

Comment: why not DLLs? that's exactly what's happening. See here: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Comment: Python-the language? Python-the interpreter? Python-the byte code parser? Somewhere before doing something on your screen, it stops being "Python" and is just one program calling another.

Comment: Python's C (and the C++) interface is well documented.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

cPython has two main ways to call C code: either by loading a shared library and calling its symbols, or by packing C code as Python binary modules and then calling them from Python code as though they were ordinary Python modules, which is how high performance stuff in the standard library is implemented - e.g. [json](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_json.c).

Loading a shared library and calling functions from it using the `ctypes` module is rather trivial, and you can find a lot of examples here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Packing your C code as binary Python module requires a lot of boilerplate and careful attention to details such as ref counting, null pointers, etc, and is documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

There are several libraries that automate the process and generate binding code for you. One example is `boost.python`:  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html

Comment: No, I don't think [json](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/json) is built in C, but using pure Python scripts

Comment: @Simon oh it definitely is: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_json.c . The python code you linked uses some import tricks to load the C parts of it transparently.

Comment: Ok. My mistake.  Maybe include the link in your answer to avoid future confusion :)